# Create dynamic preheader in exacttarget

Tags: marketing-cloud, email

For emails, I know you can create a dynamic subject line by clicking on the Lightning beside the subject line box, but I see there is no option for preheaders like that. Is there any way to create a dynamic preheader like you can with the subject lines?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Currently there is no tool/option that builds dynamic preheaders. Confusingly, the Help documentation page is named: H[ow to Create a Dynamic Subject Line and Preheader for an Email](https://help.exacttarget.com/sv/documentation/content_canvas/create_content/dynamic_content/create_a_dynamic_subject_line_and_preheader/). Some may believe this implies that there are dynamic preheader options, but this is not the case.

However, you can use Ampscript to build this dynamic logic if needed. Steps below should hopefully give you what you need:

1)  In your email, Click the Properties button. 
2)  In the preheader box, use the following code: %%=v(@preheader)=%% 
3)  Click Save. 
4)  Go to edit the email > Click on a Content Area > Click Create > Click Free Form orientation or HTML. 
5)  You can use the below example to define IF/ELSE logic. This will populate different Preheaders based on your rules defined.

Example:

```
%%[ 
VAR @language
SET @language = [LanguageAttribute]
IF @language == "en" THEN 
SET @preheader = "English Preheader" 
ELSEIF @language == "es" THEN 
SET @preheader = "Spanish Preheader" 
ELSE 
SET @preheader = "Default Preheader"
ENDIF 
]%%
```

More information on AMPScript can be found here:
http://help.exacttarget.com/en-US/documentation/exacttarget/content/ampscript/ampscript_syntax_guide/

Comment: Thanks so much Jeremy. I read that Help page and was super confused, they should fix that! I'll try out your script.

Answer (score 1):

Using SET @preheader works without defining it under VAR; else you can also define a preheader variable and set it using any type of logic.

Answer (score 0):

Just to add to Jeremy's answer, I can find that, if I have the ampscript in the content area, it will not work. You need to have the whole ampscript block declared and defined in the preheader field in properties.

Comment: So I attempted this solution, and I'm still not able to populate a preheader. My block Ampscript is at the top of my email in an HTML block. Here's my Ampscript. Is there something I'm doing wrong here?  %%[Var preheader, subject, Preferred_Language  IF Preferred_Language == "ENGLISH"  
THEN SET Subject = "Welcome"
SET Preheader = "Learn about all the benefits of being a customer"
ELSEIF 
@Preferred_Language == "SPANISH" 
then set Subject = "Bienvenido" 
Set Preheader = "Conozca todos los beneficios de ser un cliente"

endif]%%